# How to run the JS function after content filtered by AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have written the JavaScript to modify the DOM attribute based on the click and stored the values in local storage. So after the page loaded, it's getting the value from local storage and set the new attribute to DOM. It's working fine and able to achieve my scenario after perfectly page loaded.

```
ready(function(){ 
     let element = document.querySelector("body");
if(element.classList.contains("path-api-catalog") ){

    let name1 = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip_heading > h6");
        for (let i = 0; i < name1.length; i++) {
            let title = name1[i].innerText.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
            let titleURL = name1[i].parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.btn.primary-btn').href;
            if (localStorage.getItem(title) != null){

            if(localStorage[title]===titleURL){
                let titleDiv = name1[i].parentNode;
                titleDiv.querySelector('.bookmark-icon').setAttribute('onclick','RemoveListItem(event)');
                }
            }else{
                let titleDiv = name1[i].parentNode;
                titleDiv.querySelector('.bookmark-icon').setAttribute('onclick','SaveListItem(event)');
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But I have Ajax category filter to filtering the content. Whenever I click the filter, the content loaded through Ajax. After the Ajax, my JavaScript not modify the attribute and not executed correctly. So, how to execute the JavaScript function even after Ajax content loaded.

Comment: Please provide full example of code, specially the filter method.

Comment: Filter was created through PHP. Only DOM modifications are controlled by Javascript. So If user filter the content page will not referesh only content is filtered by AJAX call. I'm not sure how to run the JS function if DOM updated through AJAX

Comment: are you using jquery ajax?

Comment: @FirstLast yes using jquery ajax

Comment: did you put your scipt or call your functions inside the success method of ajax?